# No such filter: ' ' in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to splice together a series of images and videos with an audio overlay. This worked before, but after I added some more tracks and increased the audio volume of the voice tracks, ffmpeg suddenly gives the error `No such filter: ' '`. I don't know why this is, and for some reason, the only thing that seems to fix it is entirely removing all of the filters and mapping. The command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i DY_1.flac -loop 1 -t 19.5 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -loop 1 -t 21 -i hermanos.png -loop 1 -t 8 -i Mireddys.jpg -loop 1 -t 4 -i Yamilette.jpg -loop 1 -t 3.5 -i Jeremy.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i Jesaaelys.jpg -loop 1 -t 17 -i Daddy-Yankee.jpg -ss 68 -t 5 -i Daddy\ Yankee\ -\ Latigazo-oX8aAjtRZrc.mkv -i DY_2.flac -loop 1 -t 1.95 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -i Daddy\ Yankee\ \ \ Rompe\ HQ-1QzlcmHjTCo.mkv -i DY_3.flac -loop 1 -t 1.51 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -i Pose\ -\ Daddy\ Yankee\ \(Official\ Cartel\ version\)-dn28nlMOYfg.mp4 -i DY_4.flac -loop 1 -t 1.57 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -i Daddy\ Yankee\ _\ Dura\ \(Video\ Oficial\)-sGIm0-dQd8M.mkv -i DY_5.flac -loop 1 -t 14.81 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -i Luis\ Fonsi\ -\ Despacito\ ft.\ Daddy\ Yankee-kJQP7kiw5Fk.mkv -i DY_6.flac -loop 1 -t 0.81 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [DaddyYankee];\
 [2:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [hermanos];\
 [3:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Mireddys];\
 [4:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Yamilette];\
 [5:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Jeremy];\
 [6:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Jesaaelys];\
 [7:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee];\
 [8:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Latigazo];\
 [10:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee_2];\
 [11:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Rompe];\
 [13:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee_3];\
 [14:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Pose];\
 [16:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee_4];\
 [17:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Dura];\
 [19:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee_5];\
 [20:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Despacito];\
 [22:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee_6];\
 [DaddyYankee][hermanos][Mireddys][Yamilette][Jeremy][Jesaaelys][Daddy-Yankee][Latigazo][Daddy-Yankee_2][Rompe][Daddy-Yankee_3][Pose][Daddy-Yankee_4][Dura][Daddy-Yankee_5][Despacito][Daddy-Yankee_6]concat=n=17:v=1:a=0[outv];\
 [0:a:0]volume=1.3[DY_1];\ 
 [9:a:0]volume=1.3[DY_2];\ 
 [12:a:0]volume=1.3[DY_3];\ 
 [15:a:0]volume=1.3[DY_4];\ 
 [18:a:0]volume=1.3[DY_5];\ 
 [21:a:0]volume=1.3[DY_6];\ 
 [DY_1][8:a:0][DY_2][11:a:0][DY_3][14:a:0][DY_4][17:a:0][DY_5][20:a:0][DY_6]concat=n=11:v=0:a=1[outa];" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -r 60 provo.mp4
```

Edit: I added a semicolon at the end of my filters in an attempt to fix it. This actually, however, just broke it more once I backtracked to my working command (working version without extra semicolon shown here):

```
ffmpeg -i DY_1.flac -loop 1 -t 19.5 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -loop 1 -t 21 -i hermanos.png -loop 1 -t 8 -i Mireddys.jpg -loop 1 -t 4 -i Yamilette.jpg -loop 1 -t 3.5 -i Jeremy.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i Jesaaelys.jpg -loop 1 -t 17 -i Daddy-Yankee.jpg -ss 68 -t 5 -i Daddy\ Yankee\ -\ Latigazo-oX8aAjtRZrc.mkv -filter_complex \
       "[1:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [DaddyYankee];\
 [2:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [hermanos];\
 [3:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Mireddys];\
 [4:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Yamilette];\
 [5:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Jeremy];\
 [6:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Jesaaelys];\
 [7:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee];\
 [8:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Latigazo];\
 [DaddyYankee][hermanos][Mireddys][Yamilette][Jeremy][Jesaaelys][Daddy-Yankee][Latigazo]concat=n=8:v=1:a=0[outv];\
 [0:a:0][8:a:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -r 60 provo.mp4
```

Edit 2: I think it might have something to do with my volume changes, because this works:

```
ffmpeg -i DY_1.flac -loop 1 -t 19.5 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -loop 1 -t 21 -i hermanos.png -loop 1 -t 8 -i Mireddys.jpg -loop 1 -t 4 -i Yamilette.jpg -loop 1 -t 3.5 -i Jeremy.jpg -loop 1 -t 5 -i Jesaaelys.jpg -loop 1 -t 17 -i Daddy-Yankee.jpg -ss 68 -t 5 -i Daddy\ Yankee\ -\ Latigazo-oX8aAjtRZrc.mkv -i DY_2.flac -loop 1 -t 1.95 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -i Daddy\ Yankee\ \ \ Rompe\ HQ-1QzlcmHjTCo.mkv -i DY_3.flac -loop 1 -t 1.51 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -i Pose\ -\ Daddy\ Yankee\ \(Official\ Cartel\ version\)-dn28nlMOYfg.mp4 -i DY_4.flac -loop 1 -t 1.57 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -i Daddy\ Yankee\ _\ Dura\ \(Video\ Oficial\)-sGIm0-dQd8M.mkv -i DY_5.flac -loop 1 -t 14.81 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -i Luis\ Fonsi\ -\ Despacito\ ft.\ Daddy\ Yankee-kJQP7kiw5Fk.mkv -i DY_6.flac -loop 1 -t 0.81 -i DaddyYankee.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [DaddyYankee];\
 [2:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [hermanos];\
 [3:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Mireddys];\
 [4:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Yamilette];\
 [5:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Jeremy];\
 [6:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Jesaaelys];\
 [7:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee];\
 [8:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Latigazo];\
 [10:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee_2];\
 [11:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Rompe];\
 [13:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee_3];\
 [14:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Pose];\
 [16:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee_4];\
 [17:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Dura];\
 [19:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee_5];\
 [20:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Despacito];\
 [22:v:0]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,\
 pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2, setdar=16/9 [Daddy-Yankee_6];\
 [DaddyYankee][hermanos][Mireddys][Yamilette][Jeremy][Jesaaelys][Daddy-Yankee][Latigazo][Daddy-Yankee_2][Rompe][Daddy-Yankee_3][Pose][Daddy-Yankee_4][Dura][Daddy-Yankee_5][Despacito][Daddy-Yankee_6]concat=n=17:v=1:a=0[outv];\
 [0:a:0][8:a:0][9:a:0][11:a:0][12:a:0][14:a:0][15:a:0][17:a:0][18:a:0][20:a:0][21:a:0]concat=n=11:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -r 60 provo.mp4
```

Volume=volume was my original method, by the way, and did not work either.

Answer (score 10):

Remove the semi-colon in `[outa];`. The last filter in filter_complex should have no semi-colon.